# Shortcuts stop working

Tags: shortcut

So the shortcuts do work, but at some point they stop working. The only thing that helped was reopening a project over and over until they start working again. I have a MacBook Pro laptop and it's quite new, so I am pretty sure the problem is not with my laptop. Has anyone had the same problem? I am new to blender, so I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: i only can say - i don't have any problems with my Macbook. Maybe download another Blender version? I assume you have an M1? Did you downnload the apple silicone version?

Comment: All shortcuts stop working, or only a few? Are you sure you are not in a modal when this happens? Or that you are not trying to use shortcuts while in the wrong interaction mode or when your mouse cursor isn't on the right area?